# jQuery cycle - pause on hover

Tags: jquery

how can i pause the fadein / fadeout cycle when you hover the div?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divs = $('.cm-slide-page').hide(),
    i = 0;
    (function cycle() {
    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800, cycle);
    i = ++i % divs.length;
    })();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cm-slide-page">text 1</div>
<div class="cm-slide-page">text 2</div>
<div class="cm-slide-page">text 3</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cm-slide-page { display: none; }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You basically have recursive call to cycle() which has multiple animations of opacity. Do you need it to stop at any time, or just in the fully off/on visible states?

Comment: I just need it to stop when you hover the mouse over the active div

Comment: I mean, do you need it to stop any any point in the animation (harder) or just when it is fully hidden or fully shown (easier)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/zinir/4/edit)**

```
var divs = $('.cm-slide-page'),
    n = divs.length,
    i = 0,
    itv = null;

divs.hide().eq(i).show();

function cycle() {
    itv = setInterval(function(){
        divs.eq(i++%n).fadeIn(800).siblings().fadeOut(800);
    }, 3000);
}

divs.hover(function( ev ){
    return ev.type=="mouseenter" ? clearInterval(itv) : cycle();
});

cycle(); // Start !!!
```

This will have a nicer fade transition from one to other, to achieve that use also:

```
.cm-slide-page {
  position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divs = $('.cm-slide-page').hide(),
    i = 0;
    (function cycle() {
        divs.eq(i).fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800, cycle).mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop(true, false).mouseout(function(){
        cycle($(this));
    });
    });
        i = ++i % divs.length;

    })
    ();

});
```